# How to define a method that receives two arguments of type T, and S which extends T in java?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

While studying Java Generics, I was wondering if it's possible to declare a method that receives two arguments, the first of which is of generic type T, and the second one is of generic type S, which extends (or is the same type as) T. So I started to experiment on this, and wrote the following method declaration:

```
public static <T, S extends T> void testMethod(T t, S s)
{
    System.out.println("We are inside testMethod.");
}
```

and then I called this method in two ways as follows:

```
java.lang.Integer num1 = new java.lang.Integer(0);
java.lang.Integer num2 = new java.lang.Integer(1);

testMethod(num1, num2);
testMethod(num1, new Object());
```

expecting the second call to cause a compile-time exception. But the program was compiled and run with no errors. Next, I changed the method `testMethod` declaration as follows:

```
public <T extends java.lang.Number, S extends T> void testMethod(T t, S s)
```

with the following calls:

```
testMethod(new Integer(0), new Double(1.1));
testMethod(new Integer(0), new Object());
```

The first call is error free, but the second one causes a compile-time error. It seems that as long as `t` and `s` are both subtypes of `java.lang.Number`, no error occurs, whether `s` is a subtype of `t` or not.

My question: How can we declare a method that receives two arguments, one of which is guaranteed to be a subtype of the other?

Comment: What you wrote works correctly, but inference doesn't work the way you think. The reason `testMethod(num1, new Object());` compiles is that the compiler can infer that `S` and `T` are both `Object`.

Comment: In the first example, the second call does not generate a compile-time error because type inference decided to call your method with `<Object, Object>`. If you want to make the call "safe", specify the types when calling the generic method: `Test.<Integer, Object>testMethod(...)`, this will generate a compilte-time error.

Comment: But Object does not extends Number

Comment: @azro that is why the second example "behaves" as OP expected, generating a compile-time error.

Comment: @jacobm I want T to be an arbitrary subtype of Object, but I want S to be restricted as a subtype of T.

Comment: As Í said: specify the types when calling the method and don't rely on type inference. As an aside: you know that you do not need to write `java.lang.`, right? This package is always implicitly imported.

Comment: The reason `testMethod(num1, new Object());` is not compiling is because `new Object()` is not an instance of `java.lang.Number`. `Number` is an instance of `Object` however.

Comment: @AjayAujla You got the question wrong. The question is: why does the second example of the first case compile?

Comment: @Hedayat Yes, and that is what your code does. I think what you mean is that in your first example you want Java type inference to infer the type of `T` as `Integer`, rather than, say, `Number` or `Object` (all of which are valid types for the expression `num1`). If Java chose the type of `num1` as `Integer`, the line wouldn't compile, as you can verify by specifying type arguments directly (`this.<Integer, Object>testMethod(num1, num2);` doesn't compile). But Java finds that `this.<Object, Object>testMethod(num1, num2);` does compile and uses that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. In terms of generics, any type is a subtype of itself. There's no way to declare `S extends T` such that `S` and `T` can't be the same type. Furthermore, even if it were possible, it wouldn't have much of an effect here, because any instance of `S` could also be passed as `T`.
2. Type inference does its best to make the method compile. If `S` is not compatible with the type of the first argument, the compiler will infer the nearest common ancestor as `T`. You can avoid this issue by explicitly specifying `T` when you call the method:

   ```
   ThisClass.<Integer, Integer>testMethod(1, 2);    // compiles
   ThisClass.<Integer, Integer>testMethod(1, 2.0);  // does not compile
   ```

The fact is that, ultimately, the method itself can't enforce the requirement that `S` is a subtype of (or even compatible with) `t`'s type. I don't think there's any way to work around that.

Comment: You could enforce it at execution time through `t.getClass().isAssignableFrom(s.getClass())`. But there is not compile-time reinforcement except for explicit generics binding.